# Button increase font size / button decrease font size in Xcode

Tags: uilabel, xcode4.3, font-size

How can i add to my application two buttons to increase / decrease font size of a text loaded from a database into a Label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a UIStepper with the following code :

```
- (IBAction)ChangeFontSize:(id)sender {
    [labelText setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[fontStep value]]];
}
```